# Replace boolean value using bash/shell in a class

Tags: c#, bash, shell

Lets say I have a class as follows:

```
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static bool FirstClass = false;
}
```

And I'm trying to replace the value to

> true

using `sed -i '' 's/FirstClass = "[^"]*"/FirstClass = "'true'"/' ${PATH_TO_FILE}`
but the value is unchanged when I do

```
echo "##[section][Pre-Build Action] - Config.cs File content:"
cat ${PATH_TO_FILE}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Shell

```
# Update Config.cs
   echo "##[command][Pre-Build Action] - Updating Config.cs"
   sed  -i 's/FirstClass =[ \t]*false/FirstClass = true/' ${CONFIG_FILE}

echo "##[section][Pre-Build Action] - Config.cs File content:"
cat ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

For reference I'm running on a Mac and so is the build server

Comment: Your attempt works when the value `false` is between the quotes as `"false"`

Comment: sed is working as a stream processor, ie. the result is written to the standard output. You should redirect it to a temporary file which you can move onto the original one thereafter.

Comment: @Inian Thats right, but its a bool value so how do I go about changing that?

Comment: @envyM6: Are you suggesting that it could or could not be under quotes and can't be predicted?

Comment: @envyM6 look at my answer

Comment: Watch the whitespacing on this, guys. It *could* be really, *really* odd and still be valid.... Are we even 100% certain this will always be on the same line?

Comment: I would suggest that value should be in a config file, so you don't need to edit your source files to modify it.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
sed  -i 's/FirstClass =[ \t]*false/FirstClass = true/' ${PATH_TO_FILE}
```

Example :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static bool FirstClass = false;
}
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ sed -i  's/FirstClass =[ \t]*false/FirstClass = true/' f
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static bool FirstClass = true;
}
```

Also works if I can add spaces or tab before the *false* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static bool FirstClass =    false;
}
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ sed -i  's/FirstClass =[ \t]*false/FirstClass = true/' f
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static bool FirstClass = true;
}
```

or of course if there none of them

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static bool FirstClass =false;
}
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ sed -i  's/FirstClass =[\t ]*false/FirstClass = true/' f
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static bool FirstClass = true;
}
```

---

**Edit**

Under MacOS it is needed to use the option `-e` when there are other option(s), so

```
sed  -i -e "s/FirstClass =[ \t]*false/FirstClass = true/" ${PATH_TO_FILE}
```

Comment: what is your shell ? Try replacing ' by "

Comment: @envyM6 and what I can do with your remark ? you do not show the contents of the file before and efter

Comment: do you have error messages when you execute it ? Do like I did indicating execution

Comment: @envyM6 are you sure of the value of `${PATH_TO_FILE}` ?

Comment: yeah I can see the output

Comment: @envyM6 what shell executes the script ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191641/discussion-between-envym6-and-bruno).

Comment: @envyM6 back home, it is needed to use the option `-e`, I edited my answer

Comment: Not to worry! Thanks for all the help and you got the credit for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to look for the line, and then substitute, rather than trying to substitute on all lines:

```
sed '/public static bool FirstClass/s/false/true/'
```

Comment: Do i need to write it back to the file?

Comment: Of course.  I did not want to prejudice whether you used `-i` or piped to a new file to check it first.  I thought I'd leave that to your discretion.

Comment: No idea what you mean. Yes I'm updating the original file. How can I go about doing it?

Comment: Just as you did in your original post... with the `-i` option on `sed`.  Or, you can run `sed '/public static bool FirstClass/s/false/true/' ${PATH_TO_FILE} > mytempfile.java`, then eye-ball `mytempfile.java` to make sure you didn't break anything before running `mv mytempfile.java ${PATH_TO_FILE}` to replace your original.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else loosing their cool can simply use this to get things done.

```
sed -i -e 's/FirstClass = false/FirstClass = true/g' ${PATH_TO_FILE}


                                  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```